# Where is declared FirebaseAppInvite?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

When I use this code:

```
import com.google.firebase.appinvite;
FirebaseAppInvite invite = FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(data);
```

I find this error:

> error: cannot find symbol
>   FirebaseAppInvite invite FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(data);
>   symbol: class FirebaseAppInvite

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its compile issue?

Comment: thanks shalu, finally i found the problem it's was import com.google.firebase.appinvite.FirebaseAppInvite;

Answer (score 3):

Add the below dependency for Firebase Invites to your app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
          implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:12.0.1'
 }
```

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android)

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:12.0.1 is empty: https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/12.0.1/firebase-invites-12.0.1.aar :( so where is located the jar ?

Comment: Then put in libs folder and add it as library. Just try

Comment: thanks yes it's solve, i simply need to use import com.google.firebase.appinvite.FirebaseAppInvite;

Answer (score 0):

ok i found it's not

```
import com.google.firebase.appinvite;
```

but

```
import com.google.firebase.appinvite.FirebaseAppInvite;
```

Comment: Really interesting.. :)